# Convert 80-bit Double to BigDecimal

Tags: java, floating-point, aiff

*tl;dr - How do I convert the binary of a IEEE 754 80-bit floating point number into a Java BigDecimal or Double?*

---

I'm writing an `.aiff` file parser in Java following the specification found [here](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/AIFF/Docs/AIFF-C.9.26.91.pdf).

I've hit my first major roadblock with what that spec defines as the "`extended`" data format;

> extended: 80 bit IEEE Standard 754 floating point number (Standard Apple Numeric Environment [SANE] data type Extended).

It's used *once* in the file to describe the sample rate of the sound (so it's pretty important).

I have no idea how to convert these 10-bytes into a Java `Double` or `BigInteger`. `Double.longBitsToDouble()` only allows me to use the 8-bytes of the `Long` type and `BigDecimal` lacks any methods for interpreting byte arrays.

---

Then again, I am assuming I'm supposed to receive a number akin to 48khz or 44.1khz. Here's some debug output from my program;

```
Parsing AIFF File (foo.aif)
[Header: FORM, 6461086 bytes]
[Header: COMT, 410 bytes]
[Header: COMM, 18 bytes]
Sample rate: 3.025021223671622E23
[Header: CHAN, 32 bytes]
[Header: SSND, 6460590 bytes]
```

Where I attempt to calculate the the sample rate using the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4448898/4901988) (I doubted it would work);

```
byte[] sampleRateBytes = new byte[10];
inputStream.read(sampleRateBytes);
BigInteger intermediateRep = new BigInteger(sampleRateBytes);
sampleRate = new BigDecimal(intermediateRep);
```

Comment: Java doesn't have an 80-bit floating point type. You'll have to either find a library that does that (that question is off-topic here) or write your own code to interpret the various bit fields in the 80-bit float.  64-bit format has an 11-bit exponent, while 80-bit format has a 15-bit exponent.  This shouldn't be that hard to do.

Comment: See also: [x86 80-bit floating point type in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33419039/5221149)